# How to parse a text file by either unique identifying header or FF form feed char?

Tags: vb.net, csv, parsing, text, streamreader

I have a text file that comes from a credit report agency.  The text files come with unique file numbers which i am able to search for using regex.  The problem is, the data i want to extract per file number is never in the exact location.

For instance, if in the text file i have a file number TP067283, the date of birth or social security number maybe be in one column one time or different for another file number.

What is constant is that for every unique file number there is a unique Header "TransUnion Credit Report" and it terminates with "END OF TRANSUNION REPORT".

And between these 2 headers the data will be in there.

For example:

```
RF_TP067283               TRANSUNION CREDIT REPORT                          

 <FOR>          <SUB NAME>          <MKT SUB>  <INFILE>   <DATE>      <TIME> 
 (I) Y CH0001434                     06 CH     12/16      05/21/19    10:22CT

 <SUBJECT>                                          <SSN>                    
 TA****, K**                                        ###-##-####              
 <CURRENT ADDRESS>                                               <DATE RPTD> 
 1307 Blah CT., WHEELING IL. 66666                                12/16       
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 S P E C I A L   M E S S A G E S                                             
 ****IDVISION ALERTS : CLEAR FOR ALL SEARCHES PERFORMED***                   
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 M O D E L   P R O F I L E                                                   
 ***RECOVERY MODEL 1.0: NOT SCORED: INSUFFICIENT CREDIT***                   
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------


                             END OF TRANSUNION REPORT                        
                                                                            
RF_TP067284               TRANSUNION CREDIT REPORT                          

 <FOR>          <SUB NAME>          <MKT SUB>  <INFILE>   <DATE>      <TIME> 
 (I) Y CH0001434                     07 RK      4/05      05/21/19    10:22CT

 <SUBJECT>                                          <SSN>        <BIRTH DATE>
 P****, A*****  K.                                 ***-**-****   2/87       

 <CURRENT ADDRESS>                                               <DATE RPTD> 
 93 W. AUBURNDALE AV., CORTLAND IL. 66666                        10/06       

 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 S P E C I A L   M E S S A G E S                                             
 ****IDVISION ALERTS : CLEAR FOR ALL SEARCHES PERFORMED***                   
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 M O D E L   P R O F I L E                                                   
 ***RECOVERY MODEL 1.0 SCORE +519  : ***                                     
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 C R E D I T   S U M M A R Y      * * *    T O T A L  F I L E  H I S T O R Y 
 PR=0 COL=5  NEG=13 HSTNEG=0     TRD=27 RVL=11 INST=16 MTG=0  OPN=0  INQ=9  
 C R E D I T  R E P O R T  S E R V I C E D  B Y :                            
 TRANSUNION                                                    800-888-4213  
 2 BALDWIN PLACE, P.O. BOX 1000 CHESTER, PA 19016                            
 CONSUMER DISCLOSURES CAN BE OBTAINED ONLINE THROUGH TRANSUNION AT:          
      HTTP://WWW.TRANSUNION.COM                                              

                             END OF TRANSUNION REPORT
```

The file numbers are always on the top left with the header row. The information i want to extract is always in between.

But say for instance like below, The first file has a  and the social directly below it. But it has no .  And sometimes they're never in the same position.

What i already tried was Streamreader but if a file number is missing a date of birth or social, i'll have uneven columns of data since data is missing.

Here's my code so far:

```
Dim textfile = "C:\Users\username\DeskTop\Fucked up sample data.txt"


Sub Main()
Dim foundfileNumbers = FindFileNumbers(textfile)
    For Each filenumber In foundfileNumbers
        getFileNumberData(filenumber.ToString, textfile)
        'Console.WriteLine(filenumber.ToString)
    Next
End Sub




    Public Function FindFileNumbers(ByVal textfile As String)
        Dim filereader As New System.IO.StreamReader(textfile)
    Dim pages As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    Do While filereader.Peek() <> -1

        Dim regexPattern = "TP[0-9]{6}"
        Dim reg = New Regex(regexPattern)

        Dim currenttext As String = Nothing

        Dim textline As String = filereader.ReadLine()
        currenttext = textline.Substring(0, 77)
        currenttext.IndexOf("", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        Dim matches = reg.Matches(currenttext)

        For Each m In matches
            'Console.WriteLine(m.ToString)
            pages.Add(m.ToString)
        Next m


    Loop
    Return pages

End Function
```

This is where i get stuck:

```
    Public Function getFileNumberData(ByVal filenumber As String, ByVal textfile As String) As String
            Dim returnElement As String = Nothing
            Dim filereader As New System.IO.StreamReader(textfile)


            Do While filereader.Peek() <> -1

                Dim textline = filereader.ReadLine()
                If textline.Substring(0, 77).Contains(filenumber) Then
                Do While filereader.Peek() <> -1
                    Dim textline2 = filereader.ReadLine()
                    If textline2.Substring(0, 77).Contains("BIRTH DATE")Then
                        Dim textline3 = filereader.ReadLine()
                        returnElement = textline3.Substring(0, 77)
                        Console.WriteLine(returnElement)
                    Else
                        returnElement = "No DOB"
                        Console.WriteLine(returnElement)
                    End If


                Loop
            End If


        Loop
        Return returnElement
    End Function
```

So right there since it could not find "BIRTH DATE" it just gives me "No DOB" for every line that does not have it.....

Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to see the problem. The SSN seems to be at a fixed X,Y position on the screen in both cases, and can be extracted on that basis - that is, starting at the beginning of the file, advance 6 lines, then advance about 40 columns, and there is your value.

If you wanted to be belt-and-braces, you could probably check for the existence of the field header `<SSN>`, and read the value starting from the same column position at a line below (or not read at all if the header isn't present on the screen).

Comment: I would be talking to the agency and refusing to work with such a pile of data

Comment: @Steve Thats just one example, but sometimes that SSN is NOT 6 lines below, i have found that sometimes its on the 8th or 9th line at random.  And sometimes and pushed to the right or left 2 to 3 columns.

Comment: @Pr0x1mo, in such cases, where is the field header? That is what you need to find first, and then offset from it. The files you have are obviously screen-scrapes or reports from a mainframe system, and there is likely to be only a limited number of configurations of layout, and it is usual (though not guaranteed) that such older systems were usually written to a high and consistent standard. The data you have may not look structured, and isn't tailored to machine parsing, but it is structured and shouldn't pose a parsing problem.

Comment: @Steve The header that always begins a new File number with all the data i need for that file is "TRANSUNION CREDIT REPORT"

So my question would be, how would i do a search starting at the header and then terminating before reaching the next "TRANSUNION CREDIT REPORT" ?

Comment: @steve Also, the header that is always there "TRANSUNION CREDIT REPORT" its always there but sometimes it can be shifted a few columns left or right which is why i was using the Substring().Contains() method

Comment: @Pr0x1mo, just search for the field header `<SSN>`, then drop one line below and, starting at the same column as the opening angle bracket, read the 13 characters. You get the idea of how this works surely. And if you have multiple reports per file, just repeat the process of looking for the next occurrence of the SSN field header.

Comment: @Steve Look below at my solution..... It works great, but i'm wondering if you'd change or do anything differently in what i wrote?

Comment: @Pr0x1mo, if it's working then you're sorted. If I had approached it, I probably would first have parsed the text into an abstraction that allowed characters to be addressed in an XY fashion like a console screen. This is more consistent with the structure of the data. You have also interleaved other operations like the building of a PDF together with the parsing - I would have tried to separate these out into separate steps, first parsing the data in full into a list of records (defining a strongly-typed class for the purpose), and then writing the PDF or output to screen in a separate step.

Answer (score 0):

So after thoroughly going over this, i found a solution by using a regex pattern, finding a keyword and adding the correct number of indices to it so that the code can find the value directly beneath the regex pattern keyword.

My code also separates each file till its footer row and makes a separate PDF, so this code includes all of that.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Path
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports iTextSharp.text
Module Module1
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorksheet1 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim CBR = Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "CBR")
    Dim textfile = "C:\Users\username\DeskTop\CBR large data.txt"

    Dim TextFileFolder = Combine(CBR, "Text Files")
    Sub Main()
        If Not Directory.Exists(CBR) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(CBR)
        End If
        If Not Directory.Exists(TextFileFolder) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(TextFileFolder)
        End If
        Dim rmt = "C:\Users\xborja\DeskTop\CBR large data.txt"

        xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
        xlWorksheet1 = CType(xlWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)
        xlWorksheet1.Cells(1, 1) = "FILENO"
        xlWorksheet1.Cells(1, 2) = "NUMBER"
        xlWorksheet1.Cells(1, 3) = "DOB"
        xlWorksheet1.Cells(1, 4) = "HIGH RISK"
        xlWorksheet1.Cells(1, 5) = "SCORE"
        xlWorksheet1.Cells(1, 6) = "PR"
        xlWorksheet1.Cells(1, 7) = "MTG"
        xlWorksheet1.Range("C:C").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"




        Dim reader = File.OpenText(textfile)
        Dim builder = New StringBuilder(9000)
        'Allocate a reasonable size buffer to avoid mem allocs
        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine
        Dim counter = 0
        While (Not (line) Is Nothing)
            counter += 1

            builder.AppendLine(line)
            If line.Contains("END OF TRANSUNION REPORT") Then

                CheckAndProcess(builder.ToString)


                builder.Clear()
            End If

            line = reader.ReadLine

        End While

        xlWorkbook.SaveAs(CBR & "/" & System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & " CBR.xlsx")
        xlWorkbook.Close(True)
        Process.Start("explorer.exe", CBR)



        xlApp.Quit()
        releaseObject(xlApp)
        releaseObject(xlWorkbook)
        releaseObject(xlWorksheet1)
    End Sub
    Public Sub CheckAndProcess(ByVal page As String)
        Dim filenumber = Nothing
        Dim foundfileNumbers = FindFileNumbers(textfile)
        Dim BirthDateidx = Nothing
        Dim SSNidx = Nothing
        Dim ScoreIdx = Nothing
        Dim PRidx = Nothing
        Dim MTGidx = Nothing
        Dim DOB = Nothing
        Dim SSN = Nothing
        Dim Risk = Nothing
        Dim PR = Nothing
        Dim MTG = Nothing
        Dim Score = Nothing

        Dim pdfDoc As New Document()

        For Each filenumber In foundfileNumbers

            If page.Contains((filenumber)) Then
                Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("C:\Users\xborja\Desktop\CBR\Text Files\" & filenumber & ".pdf", FileMode.Create))
                pdfDoc.Open()
                pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph(page))

                counter += 1
                xlWorksheet1.Cells(counter + 1, 1) = filenumber
                If Not page.Contains("BIRTH DATE") Then
                    Console.WriteLine("no DOB")
                    DOB = " "
                    xlWorksheet1.Cells(counter + 1, 3) = DOB

                Else
                    BirthDateidx = page.IndexOf("BIRTH DATE") + 78 'returning birth date index plus enough characters to go to next line
                    Console.WriteLine(page.Substring(BirthDateidx, 5).Replace(" ", "0"))
                    DOB = page.Substring(BirthDateidx, 5).Replace(" ", "0")
                    xlWorksheet1.Cells(counter + 1, 3) = DOB

                End If

                If Not page.Contains("SSN") Then
                    Console.WriteLine("no ssn")
                    SSN = " "
                    xlWorksheet1.Cells(counter + 1, 8) = SSN

                Else
                    SSNidx = page.IndexOf("SSN") + 78
                    Console.WriteLine(page.Substring(SSNidx, 11))
                    SSN = page.Substring(SSNidx, 11)
                    xlWorksheet1.Cells(counter + 1, 8) = SSN

                End If

                If page.Contains("CLEAR FOR ALL SEARCHES PERFORMED") Then
                    Risk = "N"
                    xlWorksheet1.Cells(counter + 1, 4) = Risk
                    Console.WriteLine("N")

                Else
                    Risk = "Y"
                    xlWorksheet1.Cells(counter + 1, 4) = Risk
                    Console.WriteLine("Y")

                End If
                If Not page.Contains("RECOVERY MODEL 1.0 SCORE") Then
                    Console.WriteLine("no score")
                    Score = " "
                    xlWorksheet1.Cells(counter + 1, 5) = Score
                Else
                    ScoreIdx = page.IndexOf("RECOVERY MODEL 1.0 SCORE") + 26
                    Console.WriteLine(page.Substring(ScoreIdx, 3))
                    Score = page.Substring(ScoreIdx, 3)
                    xlWorksheet1.Cells(counter + 1, 5) = Score

                End If

                If page.Contains("PR=") Then
                    PRidx = page.IndexOf("PR=") + 3
                    Console.WriteLine(page.Substring(PRidx, 1))
                    PR = page.Substring(PRidx, 1)
                    xlWorksheet1.Cells(counter + 1, 6) = PR

                Else
                    Console.WriteLine("NO PR")
                    PR = "0"
                    xlWorksheet1.Cells(counter + 1, 6) = PR

                End If

                If page.Contains("MTG=") Then
                    MTGidx = page.IndexOf("MTG=") + 4
                    Console.WriteLine(page.Substring(MTGidx, 1))
                    MTG = page.Substring(MTGidx, 1)
                    xlWorksheet1.Cells(counter + 1, 7) = MTG

                Else
                    Console.WriteLine("NO MTG")
                    MTG = "0"
                    xlWorksheet1.Cells(counter + 1, 7) = MTG

                End If

            End If


            File.AppendAllText("C:\Users\xborja\Desktop\CBR\Text Files\" & filenumber & ".txt", page)

        Next
        pdfDoc.Close()

    End Sub
    Public Function FindFileNumbers(ByVal textfile As String)
        Dim filereader As New System.IO.StreamReader(textfile)
        Dim pages As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        Do While filereader.Peek() <> -1

            Dim regexPattern = "TP[0-9]{6}"
            Dim reg = New Regex(regexPattern)

            Dim currenttext As String = Nothing

            Dim textline As String = filereader.ReadLine()
            currenttext = textline.Substring(0, 77)
            currenttext.IndexOf("", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            Dim matches = reg.Matches(currenttext)

            For Each m In matches

                pages.Add(m.ToString)
            Next m


        Loop
        Return pages

    End Function
    Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal aCell As Object)
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(aCell)
            aCell = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            aCell = Nothing
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
        End Try
    End Sub



End Module
```